# Email send from content builder send flow

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I'm trying to send an email using content builder send flow, at the time of selecting the audience, i'm selecting Salesforce campaign and clicking on next to check the checkbox "this information is correct and ready to send" and when the send  button is enabled, i clicked on send but after sometime i get a error message saying

> There was an error sending this Email

Email doesn't contain any ampscript code.

Any idea what cloud be the issue with the send?

Comment: your mail contain any amp script code?

Comment: please refer  this link you get some idea https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lBurQAE

Comment: @Abhishek - can you post what you did to solve your issue as an answer for others to reference if they have the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i went to admin settings and checked if the user is integrated with salesforce or not, and i was that my user name was not integrated. I clicked on integrate and then refreshed the page. Went back and followed the same procedure to send an email using content builder send flow and selected salesforce campaign and email was sent.